# Need Assistance on Infinite Scrolling Banner on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a question in regards to building an Infinite Scrolling Banner on a website I'm working on.

I made it by putting all my images on one image and having it scroll across the screen above my footer.

2 issues I'm having, the image is overlapping my outside container, I want it to just show up in the designated area for my content. Also my image isn't repeating it will scroll through the whole image and then start over, I was wondering if I can have the image run on repeat and no overlap my container outside it looks bad.

Here is the code I wrote for it, I would really appreciate any help from you guys, and I'd like to thank you in advance for helping me out.

This is the layout for the code.

```
<div class="photobanner" style="display: inline-block; height: 150px; width: 2500px; overflow: hidden;">
<img class="first" src="https://www.dcnevents.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/ScrollingSponsor-1.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

This is the styling I've done for the code:

```
    @keyframes "bannermove" {
     0% {
        margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
       margin-left: -2150px;
     }

    }

    @-moz-keyframes bannermove {
     0% {
       margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
       margin-left: -2150px;
     }

    }

    @-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
     0% {
       margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
       margin-left: -2150px;
     }

    }

    @-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
     0% {
       margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
       margin-left: -2150px;
     }

    }

    @-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
     0% {
       margin-left: 0px;
     }
     100% {
       margin-left: -2150px;
     }

    }
 .photobanner img{
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
        transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    }
    p .first{
        -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite; 
           -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite; 
            -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite; 
             -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite; 
                animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite; 
        display:inline-block; 
    }
```

Comment: Your code is missing a div before the `img` element

Comment: <div class="photobanner" style="display: inline-block; height: 150px; width: 2500px; overflow: hidden;"> sorry I thought I added this before

Comment: @HassanSani I apprecaite it, I had the code, I guess when I copied and pasted I left out that Div, but even with the DIV it's not working correctly any other suggestions hwo to fix it?